# How to align an image, bottom right of table cell by using CSS?

Tags: html, css, image, alignment, css-tables

How do I set an image to the bottom right of a table cell using CSS? I have no included code as it would just be an image and a table cell.

Comment: I would use a background and background-position attribute, but you didn't include what you need, you just said you have a table, a cell and an image, in soma cases a background images would go better than an inline image and on other cases it won't

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Like so:

```
td { text-align: right; vertical-align: bottom; }
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/2DbKX/)

Comment: the only problem being that I will also have text in the cell which will need to be centrally aligned

Comment: Then add a div and make the image absolute, or use background image instead.